# Premium Economy Class Seat Availability on British Airways

Tags: seating, british-airways

Is there a way to see available seats before purchasing in Premium Economy Class on British Airways? I have already read the answers/tips in the linked duplicate "Can I see which seats are available on a British Airways flight before I book?" Those solutions work when booking Economy or Business Class, but none of those solutions work when trying to book Premium Economy. Any further suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: None of those options seem to work when trying to book in Premium Economy.

Comment: probably best to edit your question explaining that you have read and tried what is suggested in the linked duplicate, and why/how it didn't work.

Comment: Why didn't it work?

Comment: You get to the page where you enter passenger details, and the section/button for Seat selection just isn't there. I tried filling in my passenger details and continuing to the next page, but on the next page you're required to enter your credit card information and pay.

Comment: May I ask what flight, and/or what aircraft type were you flying on?

Comment: ORD to LHR via PHL and LHR back to ORD. 2533/68 and 295.

Comment: I think I figured it out. See the answer I posted.

Answer (score 1):

Alright, I have an answer. I was doing my search using the multi-city option, because I didn't see the via PHL route in the list of flights. However, I did the search again, clicking on the "more flight options" instead and it works - allows you to select seats. Using the multi-city option is apparently what screws things up.

Comment: The Multi-City flight interface is quite a bit more basic than the normal in (eg you don't get the list of different classes and fares to pick between), because the rest of it is more complicated, ]so it's not that surprising that the seat part has been cut back too

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried doing this online. However, my advice is to call the BA agent, and check which seats are available in any seat class that you're looking for.

This is what I have done whenever I want to preview the seats and see how full is the flight without purchasing the ticket. The advantage to this, is that the agent can also put a hold on your flight for 24 hours without purchase so that the price of the ticket won't change if you decide to do additional research over the next 24 hours.